# Caliburn.Micro Screen.CanClose() and MessageDialog().ShowAsync()

Tags: caliburn.micro, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

I'm currently using Caliburn.Micro 2.0 for my Windows Phone 8.1 project (Universal App) and I'm having problem with conditionally cancelling page close after user clicks a MessageDialog button.

It seems that Caliburn closes page after leaving CanClose() method, not waiting for the callback which is called after async MessageDialog.

```
public class MyViewModel: Screen
{
  public override async void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
  {     
    MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Close?","Confirmation");
    dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand() { Id = 0,  Label = "Yes" });
    dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand() { Id = 1,  Label = "No"  });       

    var result = await dlg.ShowAsync();

    callback((int)result.Id == 0);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I have at the moment is set a field with a flag indicating if the page can be closed. On the user attempt to navigate back I tell Caliburn to abort the close and I display the confirmation dialog. When I get the result I set the flag to true and navigate back manually. This causes another call to CanClose, but this time I set the callback to true and skip the dialog part.

I don't like this solution much, but it is only way I managed to solve this problem.

```
private bool canClose = false;

public override async void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
{
  callback(canClose);

  if (!canClose)
  {
    MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Close?","Confirmation");
    dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand() { Id = 0,  Label = "Yes" });
    dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand() { Id = 1,  Label = "No"  });       

    var result = await dlg.ShowAsync();

    if ((int)result.Id == 0)
    {
      canClose = true;
      navigationService.GoBack();
    }
  }
}
```

PS: I don't use MessageDialog directly in my ViewModel, I'm using a dialog service interface for popups. I just used it here to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While the enhancement [CanClose](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/86) isn't set, this is my approach utilize `Navigating event` to solve this 'problem'

If user could just **GoBack()** would be easy to handle, but in my case, there's many options to navigate. So, the only way that I found to solve it is described below:

```
public MyViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    _navigationService.Navigating += OnGoBack;
}

private async void OnGoBack(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;

    var dlg = new MessageDialog("Close?", "Confirmation"); //Dialog for demo purpose only!
    dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand() { Id = 0, Label = "Yes" });
    dlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand() { Id = 1, Label = "No" });
    var result = await dlg.ShowAsync();

    if ((int) result.Id != 0) return;
    _navigationService.Navigating -= OnGoBack;
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        _navigationService.GoBack();
    else
    {
        var myViewModel = Type.GetType($"YourNameSpaceViewModels.{e.SourcePageType.Name}Model");
        _navigationService.NavigateToViewModel(myViewModel);
    }
}
```

Explaination:
`$"YourNameSpaceViewModels.{e.SourcePageType.Name}Model"`

*Here I get the full path to my class where user want to goto*

And so, I navigate to it `_navigationService.NavigateToViewModel(myViewModel);`